# How to send data continuously from server to browser

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, node.js, cgi

I have a file with the contents:

id,value,location 
1234,pass,/temp/...
234,fail,/temp/r/...
2343,pass,/temp/status/...

The above file is update for about 1 hour continuously by some program. I need to send this file information to the browser and create a table and show all the data dynamically whenever user enters the link http://localhost:6666/getdata. How do I achieve this with:

```
1.cgi (python or perl)
or
2.nodejs
or
3.bottle framework.
as the backend.
```

There could be 10k entries after 1 hour.
Let us say the file was create at 12:00PM and a user requested http://localhost:6666/getdata at 12:10 PM. For next 50 minutes the data has to updated dynamically(continuously) which would feel like live data for the user.

Comment: You could use socket.io with node to create a real live connection

Comment: Yeah socket.io would definitely help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To regularly send data from server to client, the usual design would be for the client to establish either a webSocket or socket.io connection to the server.  That connection will then be long-lived and data can be sent either direction over the connection.

This allows the server to send data to the client whenever it wants to without waiting for the client to ask for data.  The client then listens for that incoming data on the existing connection (with the appropriate event handlers) and processes the data when it arrives - doing whatever is appropriate for the data (like displaying it).

The [socket.io library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/docs) is a higher level abstraction built on top of webSocket and it offers a number of useful features beyond what webSocket offers (such as auto-reconnect, auto-detection of a dropped or non-function connection, a messaging layer, etc...) which are generally helpful (which is why that library is so popular for this use).  There are socket.io libraries for both use in a browser and for many server platforms (including node.js).

Comment: Could you please provide a small code snippet for front-end(javascript) and backend (cgi with python or perl)?

Comment: @Somebody - The socket.io doc shows code snippets for front-end (Javascript) and back-end (node.js).  If you want to use a different back-end than node.js, you can find a socket.io library for that platform and follow its documentation.  You can't really do CGI with socket.io or webSocket (without some special back-end support) because socket.io and webSocket require a persistent connection between browser and server which is not how CGI normally works.  But, (out of my area of expertise), but there are probably ways to make whatever environment you're using work with socket.io.

Comment: @Somebody - The client and server docs for socket.io with browser and node.js are [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/docs).  Sample apps are [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples).  There's a python socket.io server implementation [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio).  socket.io is very popular so you can find server implementations for most persistent server environments.

Comment: @Somebody - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.